# Runtime error Visual Studio and OpenCV Error while using SURF

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, runtime-error, surf, object-detection

The following code is supposed to perform feature detection using SURF in `OpenCV2.3` on Visual Studio 2010. The image "sample.jpg" is a coloured image (RGB) of a book and the video captured will consist of several different books. There is no compile error but on CTRL F5, the console says `Native' has exited with code -1073741811 (0xc000000d)`. This is strange because other programs were working fine. I tested it by deleting this feature detection code with a simple code that displays an image, and that seems to be working fine. Only when I run this code, it throws this error. I have included the following library under Additional dependencies :

```
opencv_core230d.lib
opencv_highgui230d.lib
opencv_ml230d.lib
opencv_legacy230d.lib
opencv_imgproc230d.lib
opencv_features2d230d.lib
opencv_calib3d230d.lib
opencv_flann230d.lib
```

Do I need to include a library or something for SURF as this is the first time I am working with Surf. Kindly help.

```
int main()
{
    Mat object = imread( "C:\\OpenCV2.3\\sample.jpg");

    if( !object.data )
    {
        std::cout<< "Error reading object " << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
    int minHessian = 500;

    SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
    std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object;

    detector.detect( object, kp_object );

    //Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat des_object;

    extractor.compute( object, kp_object, des_object );

    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

    VideoCapture cap(0);
if( !cap.isOpened() ) return -1;

    namedWindow("Good Matches");

    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);

    //Get the corners from the object
    obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
    obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( object.cols, 0 );
    obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( object.cols, object.rows );
    obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, object.rows );

    char key = 'a';
    int framecount = 0;
    while (key != 27)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;

        if (framecount < 5)
        {
            framecount++;
            continue;
        }

        Mat des_image, img_matches;
        std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_image;
        std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
        std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;
        std::vector<Point2f> obj;
        std::vector<Point2f> scene;
        std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
        Mat H;
        Mat image;

        cvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

        detector.detect( image, kp_image );
        extractor.compute( image, kp_image, des_image );

        matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches, 2);

        for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
        {
            if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][3].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
            {
                good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
            }
        }

        //Draw only "good" matches
        drawMatches( object, kp_object, image, kp_image, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

        if (good_matches.size() >= 4)
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
            {
                //Get the keypoints from the good matches
                obj.push_back( kp_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
                scene.push_back( kp_image[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
            }

            H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

            perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

            //Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene image )
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
            line( img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
        }

        //Show detected matches
        imshow( "Good Matches", img_matches );

        key = waitKey(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the SURF detector doesn't work on color images. You will need to load them in grayscale using

```
Mat object = imread( "C:\\OpenCV2.3\\sample.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I changed the image to a gray scaled Lena, still the error remains!Even if I donot use a video and just compare between 2 gray scaled images,the same error is thrown.

Comment: Here is the question with Images which throws the same error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638928/surffeaturedetector-error-native-has-exited-with-code-1073741811-0xc000000d

Comment: Well, I couldn't test the exact same situation you have as I only have the release build of opencv 2.49 on my laptop here (space constraints on my ssd...). The code builds and runs correctly on my latop though. Are you building in release or debug mode? I notice you are linking to debug libraries.

Comment: Well, all my other programs are running in Debug mode.When I changed to Release mode, then there were red curvy lines under all the include headers and error occurs saying  No such file or directory.Pardon me for such non technical terms,but do you suggest to run in Release mode?If so then what needs to be done?

Comment: You will need to set the include and library directories again for the release build and then specify the dependencies again. In opencv the debug versions of the libraries are differentiated from the release versions by a 'd' at the end of the filename. To link to the release versions you specify the filenames without the 'd'.

Comment: But why is it needed to run in Release mode?The other programs like video capture are running in Debug mode...so from now on do I have to run all my OpenCV programs in Release mode?

Comment: No, it was just a way of checking if the problem is with your debug build of the library.

Comment: Ok,so when I have to work with camera,then also all the frames need to be converted to gray scale when I am using SURF?And the code in Release mode works.Therefore,from now on I should use Release mode?

Comment: Yes, the SURF descriptor is only computable on grayscale images (unless something has changed that I am unaware of). If the release code is working and you need the debugging information you could try using the 'release with debug info' build type or alternatively rebuild your debug version of opencv.